# How do I modify a Haskell list without entering an infinite loop?

Tags: debugging, haskell, recursion, infinite-loop, lazy-evaluation

I am writing a piece of code in Haskell, where I have a line that does something like this:

```
addElement :: [a] -> a -> [a]
addElement list elem = list ++ [elem]
```

I need (or at least, I think so) a function like this for the purpose of adding new vertices in a vertex list of a graph data structure that I'm implementing. Now, I can call this function as follows

```
newlist = addElement oldlist elem
```

and everything works out fine. However, if I write

```
mylist = addElement mylist elem
```

and then try to do anything with mylist after the call has terminated (it does), I enter an infinite loop, and if I understand correctly this is due to the lazy evaluation of Haskell or something of the sort (`mylist` gets expanded to `addElement (addElement ... elem) elem` if I got it right ?).

This is of course bad for my particular implementation, since for my purposes I now have to make new lists every time I need to add an element to a list. So how do I make an element-adding function that works the way I want?

Comment: `mylist = addElement mylist elem` It's not an assignment, it's an equation. Haskell has no updates. Show your attempt in context. How are you trying to build mylist?

Comment: Well, I basically run `mylist = []` first, and then, say, `mylist = addElement mylist 3`. The second call is equivalent to `mylist = mylist ++ [3]`. If I then type `id mylist` in ghci for example, nothing happens and I'm stuck in the loop. So should I take it that it is impossible to have a function `addElement` in Haskell that would end up with `id mylist` resulting in `[3]` ?

Comment: No, please show an entire function you are trying to build mylist in.

Comment: If you don't need to build the list in a specific order, then adding an element at the front is the solution (it's an O(1) operation). Even if you need this specific order it's probably cheaper to build the list in the reverse order and just reverse it once in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `mylist = addElement mylist elem` is an equation, it is **not an assignment**. It is **not** evaluated once: since Haskell is a declarative language, you **cannot alter a variable**: once you give it a value, it will always have that value.

Your equation will thus result in:

```
mylist = addElement mylist elem
       = addElement (addElement mylist elem) elem
       = addElement (... (addElement mylist elem) ...) elem
```

you get the idea.

Nevertheless, you **do not need to construct an complete new list each time**: you can simply use `(h:t)` to **append to the head**:

```
addElement :: [a] -> a -> [a]
addElement t h = (h:t)
```

This will construct a "new" list in *O(1)* that reuses the old list as tail. As mentioned before the element will be added to the front.

Another way to solve the issue is using ***difference lists***. Here a list is denoted as:

```
type DiffList a = a -> [a]
```

and an empty list is:

```
emptyDiffList :: DiffList a
emptyDiffList = \x -> x
```

In that case you *ground* the difference list with:

```
groundDiffList :: DiffList a -> [a]
groundDiffList x = x []
```

and you can add an element to the **end of the list** with:

```
addElement :: DiffList a -> a -> DiffList a
addElement l el = \x -> l (el:x)
```

Nevertheless you will always need to *create a new variable* for a "new list": you cannot all of a sudden give `mylist` another value (you can of course use recursion but in that case those are technically two different variables: the `mylist` of the *caller*, and the `mylist` of the *callee*).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, I think your first and last paragraphs best answer my question. So the fact that I have to introduce new variables for each "new list" is basically something of a limitation that I have to live with in Haskell, and there is nothing I (or anyone else) can do about it. That's enough for me to accept.

Comment: @A.Sh: indeed, although it is not really a limitation: you can write any program without redefining a variable. Furthermore personally I think that is useful to have such limitation since you do not have to reason about variables changing values through the process. Declarative languages tend to be easier to debug in my opinion.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That is true, now that you say it. I'm still quite new to functional (and declarative) programming, so I guess my thinking is still biased by all the imperative programming I've done before.